# Dynamic variable name in object

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a jquery code, to get all this hidden input name and values, and put it in a data string for my `$.ajax({ .. })` post.

```
var obj = {}; //object
var arr =  []; //array
var hidden_fields = $( 'form#frm_vehicle input[type=hidden]' ).each(
        function(index){  
            var input = $(this);
            _name = ""+input.attr('name')+"";
            _val = input.val();
            obj = {
                _name : _val
            }
            arr.push(obj);
            //alert('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + ' Name: ' + input.attr('name') + ' Value: ' + input.val());
        }
    );
console.log(arr);
```

in the code above, how would i create a dynamic `_name` here

```
obj = {
        _name : _val
      }
```

or is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Comment: `var obj = {}; obj[_name_] = _val;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a legit question and there is a very nice solution to this.
in ES6, you can use dynamic object keys like this:

```
var obj = {
  [key]: 'value'
}
```

where 'key' is a variable containing the key name that you want to use.

If you cant use es6, i would go with the solution suggested by Blackhole in the comments.